# Reading files into object inside classes?

Tags: java, object, class-diagram

I am working on reading file into objects inside classes. Being new to object-oriented world I am little confused with those object class distribution from real word data. Here I am taking example as shows in below first image .  I am reading two text file 1 and file 2 data containing student id, total marks, and student class with student name. I have to store those details in a object of classes and retrieve those details into below three files with different attributes.

[list of table depicting file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEyRh.png)[image]

I have created two class diagram for this implementation and do not know exactly if I am creating a right one .. any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Do I have to have a separate class for Marks or not ..

[class diagram with 3 class- student ,marks and class 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQjqr.png)
[image]
[class diagram with 2 class - student and class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XvRT.png)

[image]

Comment: `marks` is a data which is not specific to `student` so there should be separate entity say `result` containing `student-id` and `marks`